# import single records from mysqldump

Tags: mysql

Sometimes users delete a single record in a table, how can i restore this single record from the backup i created with mysqldump.

I created the dump file with command
mysqldump -uxxx -pxxx table > table.sql

Im aware that when creating dumpfiles the WHERE statement can be used but i do not see any info or examples on the import using this.

What i would like is to restore only record x from table y out of this full dump

So are there any tips or examples for this?

Comment: 1. Open file with txt editor and find necessary data. Or 2. Imort data to an other server, then with mysql client discover necessary data.

Comment: Thats the hard way and it works but having huge files doesn't make this a good option.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin allows to export using quries. It might help.

Comment: yes export does but having a full dumpfile file i need import with a query

Answer (score 0):

Dump file is just a text file with SQL queries. You can open the file, search for the record you need and execute the query handy.

Comment: Sure this works but as mentioned above this is not a simple thing with huge files. Sure there must be a easier way to browse the data in a dumpfile and restore single records

Comment: If you use Linux, you can use grep to search in the file so quickly.

Comment: how does a scrip look like doing that, i have multiple tables in the dump so parameters would be SCRIPT <table> <record> <live system>

Comment: It should be: grep [key-word] path/to/your/file For more information, you can google with the keyword: "grep linux"

Comment: i know grep, then i find what i need but this is no way near a script that takes the single records from a table (in a sql dump file) and adds it into the live system again.

Comment: You can't execute the script directly?

Comment: thats what i ask all along... a script that might be out there doing that... if i had it i wouldn't ask but run it. Im amazed nothing seems to be there doing something i guess more people might need...

Answer (score 0):

Restore the entire dump into a dummy DB/table, export the single row that you want, then import that single row into your live DB.

Comment: also a more then one step restore, i was just wondering if no tool or script can do something directly from the dump file into the live DB

Comment: You would have to write a script that parses through the dump file to find the record you want and imports it.

Based on your other comments here, it's not clear whether you want an automated tool to do this, or whether you want to browse the records manually to select the one to restore.

Comment: a script should let me go over the records that are matching a record number/table or searchstring/table. With this i can decide what i need and this should be placed back into the live system.

Comment: Then do as I suggested: write a script to restore the dump to a dummy DB, let you browse that dummy DB and select a single record, and restore it for you. That's about as easy as you can get from a UI perspective. The script wouldn't even be all that difficult to write if you're a programmer.